# Battlechugging potions in The Witcher 2

Tags: the-witcher-2

When The Witcher 2 came out, I was immediately put off by the inability to chug potions without kneeling and navigating a bunch of menus, making alchemy, a core part of the game, useless. Has this been changed in the enhanced edition, and if not, is there a mod the game to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Quibbling with your premise: Alchemy is far from useless, it's just that it's proactive, not reactive. You should use potions to buff you *before* entering combat, not pause mid fight to take a drink. This is both in keeping with the lore from the novels, and a substantially more interesting gameplay mechanic, as it adds more depth and strategy to preparing for combat and managing resources.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I suppose a potion of health regeneration could be used proactively when entering a dungeon, but what of the more specific potions, like the one that fills your blood with poison to harm bloodsuckers?

Comment: Those *in particular* are the ones you should be using proactively. The whole idea of a Witcher per the novels is built around studying ones foes, knowing what sort of dangers to expect, and downing an assortment of potions tailored to suit them ahead of time. The game is pretty good about telegraphing what sort of baddies you need to prepare for for exactly this reason.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I guess that's just not good enough for me.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: I think 'pretty good' is an understatement. :) "There is a cave full of nekkers that you're going to go into. Here is a book on nekkers. You should read the book. IT MIGHT CONTAIN USEFUL INFORMATION. *wink wink* Would you like the only potion recipe I have for sale while you're here?"

Comment: @StuartPegg that's even worse alchemy being useless. I hope you were exaggerating.

Comment: @kotekzot: Well, maybe a little. :)

Comment: [This mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/witcher2/mods/740/) allows to put potions into quickslots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has not been changed in the Enhanced Edition.  Potion crafting and drinking is still a process that requires that you meditate, which is not something you can do in the midst of battle.

A search over at the [Witcher Mod Nexus](http://witcher.nexusmods.com/) did not turn up any mods to the game that would change this behavior.  There is one that [increases potion duration](http://witcher.nexusmods.com/mods/59), however.

Being prepared for battle before you enter it is kind of core to the Witcher series, so this is a conscious design decision made by the developers of the game.  In the first game, this was balanced slightly differently - you could drink potions in a battle situation (although it left you vulnerable for several seconds), but crafting potions required that you meditate.

Meditation was limited to specific areas, such as fires in the wilderness (which you had to light using consumables) or in inns or other friendly establishments where it was safe to sleep.

Comment: I will also say I found this frustrating to no end, and I actually stopped playing the first game because of it.  I was reluctant to start the second, until I discussed it with others and found that the best combat setup is to focus on never getting hit - the combat in this game is more "Ninja Gaiden" (move fast, abuse special moves, avoid getting hit) than "Skyrim." (tank and swing your sword as fast as possible)

Comment: I don't really see how it's core to the series, considering the first game was the exact opposite in that regard. +1 for the answer, though, I'm going to accept it after a couple of days, unless a non-Nexus mod turns up that does what I want.

Comment: @kotekzot, "series" in this case extending beyond just the two games, and into the novels and other media that predates the games.  That said, I never had much luck trying to drink in battle in Witcher 1, myself.  I always tended to get overwhelmed, so perhaps we just had different experiences with the first game :)

Comment: @kotekzot Did you never play on higher difficulties in the first game? Aside from White Raffards Decoction, all potions in the first game last for *hours*, and have no instantaneous effect. Combined with the moment of vulnerability while consuming a potion, drinking in combat was *dangerous* in the first game, though possible. Being prepared for combat has always been a core mechanic, though it was certainly re-emphasized heavily in the sequel.

Comment: I thought the first game was quite enjoyable, and the combat wasn't too hard if you were able to choose the proper stance and keep clicking at the right moment. Personally, I would wholeheartedly recommend revisiting the first game. There is a rather huge difference between books and games, and I think they've made a big mistake trying to implement a mechanic that doesn't belong in the medium.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'm not sure using the euphemistic "hours" (which actually last minutes, if not a minute) is helpful in the context. I am also not aware of any delayed-effect potions in the first game. There is no potion that gives you +x health, but the +x% boost applies immediately. I believe I've played on average difficulty, as that's what I do most of the time.

Comment: @kotekzot with the exception of the aforementioned White Raffards Decoction (which works instantaneously and has no duration), and Blizzard (which has a short duration of roughly 90 seconds real time -  typically about the length of a single combat and best used right before engaging), all potions in the first Witcher game can comfortably last through several combats, and most will easily last through an entire dungeon crawl comfortably. Swallow (the basic health regen potion) lasts for 8 minutes realtime. All others last for a whopping **32 minutes**.